# Script exit after time elapsed

Tags: python, multithreading

Basically I'm running a script and I want to run another thread parallel to it which will exit the script after 3 minutes has elapsed, I have tried this using threads and it didn't work, how would I go about doing this?

Many thanks

Comment: you want the script to run for three minutes?

Comment: `I have tried this using threads and it didn't work` posting what you tried sure would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try this, which will kill the entire process after a timeout:

```
import signal
# send SIGALRM in 3 minutes, by default killing the process
signal.alarm( 3*60 )
```